# How do I physically identify memory modules without labels and without them being in a computer?

Tags: memory, ddr, sodimm

I bought 4 used memory modules from a reputable supplier on E-Bay as PC2-4200 DDR2, but it appears that they are are not what the labels say they are. What are the precise dimensions and physical specifications I can use to identify the modules?

Comment: My memory modules were labeled as DDR2, but they wouldn't fit in my MB slots.  It had to be that they were mis-labeled.  It turns out, they are plain DDR.   As I couldn't find a difinitive answer here, I found my own answer and posted it for others.

Comment: Answers should not be included as part of questions. I've separated the two for you. However some more info below would help rather than just linking off-site (since links may  eventually die).

Comment: Thanks Karan.  I think the Micron .pdf has the most useful information.  Is there a way to preserve it, rather than just to link to it?

Comment: You can excerpt some important parts here (not everything though), but only if Micron allows it. Otherwise the general recommendation is to summarise the information in one's own words. Not sure how you can deal with images however. Perhaps find some you can use on Wikipedia or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The information can be found in [this document](https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/technical-note/dram-modules/tn0455.pdf).

[Here](http://www.simmtester.com/page/news/showpubnews.asp?num=168) is another site with actual dimensions of memory modules. No guessing!

Standard length modules (as for desktop computers) are 133.35 mm long.  They exist in *standard* and *low profile*, and maybe some other variant types.  The important thing for fitting into the slots, though, is where the notch is.  Of course, the pins are different, too, but the notches keep you from installing the wrong modules in your MB.

DDR modules have the notch 73.28mm from one end (the long side from the notch).

DDR2 modules have the notch 70.68 mm from one end (the long side from the notch).

DDR3 modules have the notch 54.68 mm from one end (the short side from the notch).

SDR modules have two notches

The right term to search for to get other measurements to identify other modules is *DIMM form factor*.  Form Factor means the physical dimensions.  So even if you are searching for new memory types, you should be able to locate the dimensions you are searching for.

Comment: Apparently, the memory was designated as "fully buffered", which means it is DDR2 server memory that has the same form factor as DDR memory.